# List of checked boxes in Pyside?

Tags: python, qt, checkbox, pyside, qt-designer

I created a gui in qtdesigner that has many checkboxes:
[Screenshot http://imgq.tk/img/-2012-07-13%2013:55:07.png](http://imgq.tk/img/-2012-07-13%2013:55:07.png)

and I would like to know if there is a way to list all the checked boxes using pyside. It would be even better if I could just get the text from each box. The boxes are in a grid layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in python, you should be able to introspect on the object and find all its members. But Qt makes this easy in general because of the parent-child relationship. You can query the form (the parent) for its children that are text boxes:

```
# my python's a bit rusty, but hopefully this is close
checkboxes = [x for x in form.children() where isinstance(x, QCheckBox)]
```

See the [findChildren()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild) and [children()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#children) methods.

Comment: Could you please help me in this query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164853/how-to-use-findchildren